# How show data from three tables in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to show data from three tables with a join, but it doesn't work.
I have three tables: `linktable`, `friends` and `carbrands`.
The columns are friendnumer, lastname and carbrands.
The table linktable must show: column friendnumber.
The table friends must show: column lastname
and table carbrands must show column brand.

my sql is:

```
SELECT friendnumber,lastname, brand
From linktable,
     friends,
     carbrands
WHERE linktable.friendnumber = friends.lastname
  and friends.lastname = carbrands.brand ;
```

What is going wrong?

Can someone help me?

thanks in advance.

Comment: What does not work? Do you get an error?

Comment: Learn to use proper `join` syntax.  Simple rule:  Never use commas in the `from` clause.

Comment: Number = name seems wrong. Name = brand also seems odd.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is lacking information. How exactly is your schema defined?

Let's assume you had the following tables:

```
friends:
+----+---------------+
| id | name          |
+----+---------------+
| 1  | alice         |
| 2  | bob           |
| 3  | carol         |
+----+---------------+

carbrands:
+----+---------------+
| id | brandname     |
+----+---------------+
| 1  | Škoda         |
| 2  | Volkswagen    |
| 3  | Ferrari       |
+----+---------------+

linktable:
+----------+---------+
| friendid | brandid |
+----------+---------+
| 1        | 3       |
| 2        | 2       |
| 2        | 1       |
+----------+---------+
```

You could then select the name of each friend and the car they drive with the following statement:

```
SELECT friends.name, carbrands.brandname
FROM friends
JOIN linktable
ON friends.id = linktable.friendid
JOIN carbrands
ON linktable.brandid = carbrands.id;
```

This will get you three rows:

Alive drives a Škoda.
Bob drives a Volkswagen and a Ferrari.